# Generating Random vectors and matrices for weights and bias

Tags: python, numpy, sigmoid

I am trying to know the chance of fire based on sensors x1 and x2.

```
y=1
```

For this, I am trying to generate random vectors and matrices for weights and bias but I get an error.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=123)
w1 = np.random.rand(4,2)
b1 = 4*1
x = np.array([0.4, 0.32])

z1 = np.dot(w1,x) + b1
a1 = 1 / (1+np.exp(-z1))

np.random.seed(seed=123)
w2 = np.random.rand(1,4)
b2 = 1*1

z2 = np.dot(w2,x) + b2
a2 = 1 /(1+np.exp(-z2))
```

But I get the error below:

```
----> 1 z2 = np.dot(w2,x) + b2
      2 a2 = np.tanh(Z1)
      3 print(a2)

ValueError: shapes (2,4) and (2,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

I am not able to figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the error - you are trying to multiply the matrices `w2` and `x`, which have invalid dimensions to be multiplied.

Matrix `w2` has 1 row and 4 columns:

```
>>> w2 = np.random.rand(1,4)
>>> w2.shape
(1, 4)
```

Matrix `x` has 2 entries:

```
>>> x = np.array([0.4, 0.32])
>>> x.shape
(2,)
```

Therefore, you cannot multiply these matrices together - matrices can only be multiplied if and only if the number of columns in the first matrix, `w2`, is equal to the number of rows in the second, `x`. Here, as the error says, `4 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`.

You can solve this by either giving `x` four rows, or `w2` two columns.

Hope this helps.